# Port changing in Apache 2.4.6 does not work

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ports, ubuntu-13.10, apache2.4

On Apache 2.4.6 I can no longer specify a port. I have tried editing the port in ports.conf and 000-default.conf to 8080 and it does not work like in Apache 2.2.2. Please note this is a fresh install of Apache on a new server.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? The only other difference between the servers is that I have Ubuntu 13.10 now instead of 12.04.3 LTS.

It recognizes the site on localhost:80, however will not see it on localhost:8080 no matter what I have changed.

Comment: I'm intending on wiping the new 13.10 installation next week and reinstalling 12.04.3 LTS from my disk, then reinstalling Apache on version 2.2.22 to keep my site compatible. The only reason being that I cannot set the port in Apache 2.4.6. If it is possible, then I will be very happy, however I think I've wasted more time trying to get this fixed than it would have taken to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04.3 in the first place. If there's a fix known for this by next week I wont downgrade.